# Position a hover-parallax on an image within a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, parallax.js

I have a parallax hover section which I have on top of some text and a CSS background image. The issue I'm having is that the section does not sit flush inside my div/header, and even worse so when I use position: absolute. I am wondering if there is a way that I can layer my header section so that the image sits at the back with the text on top, and then the parallax on top of that? I have tried z-indexing with no luck, the parallax section just sits in the corner of my header.

I am trying to achieve something like this: https://www.byalicelee.com/slack but with a CSS background image and text within. I will try and make up a codepen to elaborate but in the meantime here is what I have:

```js
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene);
```

```css
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(img/image.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 0;
}

header .row {
  width: 1150px;
}

header .new-section__white {
  background-color: transparent;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hero {
  width: 100vw;
}

.hero h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.hero img {
  width: 100%;
}

header .section-parallax {
  /*    position: absolute;*/
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.js"></script>
<header>
  <!-- ~~~ HEADER -->
  <section class="hero new-section__white">
    <div class="row new-section__inner">
      <div class="col span-1-of-2">
        <h1>Some Text - Page Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- ~~~ parallax -->
  <section class="section-parallax">
    <div id="scene">
      <div data-depth="0.2">
        <img class="yellow" src="resources/img/p1.png" alt="parallax header">
      </div>
      <div data-depth="0.4">
        <img class="purple" src="resources/img/p2.png" alt="parallax header">
      </div>
      <div data-depth="0.6">
        <img class="window" src="resources/img/p3.png" alt="parallax header">
      </div>
      <div data-depth="0.2">
        <img class="windowsquare" src="resources/img/p4.png" alt="parallax header">
      </div>
      <div data-depth="0.4">
        <img class="circle2" src="resources/img/p5.png" alt="parallax header">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
```